# Whats the best way to bundle the whole project in Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'd like to create a fat-jar which is autoexecutable (Shade Plugin), but also includes sources, resources, tests, and everything in a Eclipse-importable way.

The jar would be single-file executable app, which also contains the whole project in an importable fashion as a maven project someway (after unzipping the jar, I assume).

Another option would be a resulting project zip that includes the binary distribution at base level.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What would the wanted result look like? In terms of package / folder structure?

Comment: @Tunaki Either an executable jar with a project zip inside (maven structure) or the opposite, a zip with the jar in base or in /target I guess. The former is more suitable for non-technical user (but a dev can inspect it), the later is suitable for dev (but the executable is delivered for convneience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution requires 3 steps:

1. Create an uber-jar of the project with the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). This JAR will contain all the dependencies and will be executable.
2. Create a side artifact consisting of the sources of the project with the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). This ZIP will contain the `pom.xml` and all of the sources under `src`.
3. Create another side artitact that will effectively be our final artifact, that will contain both the unpacked shaded JAR (to make it effectively executable) and the sources ZIP.

This would be a possible configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-uberjar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>fully.classified.name.to.main.Class</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-sources.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>final</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This configures the execution of the `maven-shade-plugin` and 2 execution of the `maven-assembly-plugin`. The first execution will creates the sources ZIP. This would be the `assembly-sources.xml` assembly descriptor file:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>sources</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>pom.xml</include>
                <include>src/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

It includes `pom.xml` and everything under `src` into a ZIP having the `sources` classifier.

The second `assembly.xml` assembly descriptor file would be:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-sources</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:jar:${project.version}</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectAttachments>true</useProjectAttachments>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:zip:sources:${project.version}</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This creates 2 `<dependencySet>`. The first one unpacks the shaded JAR (which replaced the main artifact at that point in the build). The second one simply includes the `sources` ZIP attached artifact; note that we need to use [`<useProjectAttachments>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) to include the attached sources ZIP.

When you run `mvn clean install`, you will have as result a file `{finalName}-jar-with-sources.jar` that will be your wanted executable JAR. It will also contain a ZIP file of all the sources in the root folder.

Comment: Really nice answer!! But just one question, if I follow this approach (zip inside jar), can the outer jar main class be linked to the inner fat-jar main class so it is still executable?

Comment: @Whimusical Yes, the initial shaded JAR is unpacked. So it's just like the executable JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the [maven assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) gives you the best control over these kind of things, for both an uber jar or an installable zip. The shade plugin works well for uber jars, but not so well for installer zips or installers.
In the past i also augmented that functionality by adding in the mix the izpack plugin, which creates a real installer, off of the distributable zip that you create with the assembly plugin.

For example, with the assembly-plugin you can choose to include or exclude certain file resources. This happens for example when you want to use a configuration file while working with the IDE, but you really want to exclude it in the final distribution zip, or you want to include a slightly different one.
Same happens when you want to generate an rpm: the assembly plugin can help quite a bit in first preparing what's needed for the rpm plugin to operate.

The assembly plugin comes with all sort of settings, which you declare in its xml configuration file and it is well documented.

Comment: This is not really an answer but more of an extended comment.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, trying to pack all the application dependencies in a single `.jar` is a bad idea, mainly because `.jars` are not designed to be used this way. In fact, they might contain `META-INF/` and other jar-specific files that might clash each other.

When I have to build binary distributions that can be run from the command line, I use the Assembly plug-in, as [I've described in this post](https://marcobrandizi.info/my-maven-archetype-for-java-command-line-projects/). If you need to distribute a GUI application or a one-click, self-contained web server, the approach would be very similar.